# Excel Counting Occurrences Without a Preset Range

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula, formula, subtotal

Good Evening. I am trying to count how many offices each company has in each country. For instance, 24 Hour Fitness has office as follows:

```
China 2
Hong Kong 6
etc.
```

I can subtotal it, but I want it in its own column. I have tried to do this in sections, but it takes to long as the entire sheet has over 168K rows. Can someone please give me a hand?

[image: Spreadsheet Snapshot]]

Comment: PS I have a pivot table on another sheet. I can list the locations, but not total them individually. this could be another option.

Comment: Pivot table should work? Just drag Parent Company and Location into the Row field and then Country into the Value field

Comment: I tried that, I thought it would as well. It did not for some reason. I am not sure why though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you? Place in `C2` and drag down

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)
```

Comment: thank you.  that did it.  I was having a mental block, and was ready to throw the keyboard. thank you so much.